# Conversion from DQ0 to dq0 and vice-versa

Tags: power-electronics, power-engineering, power-grid

I have been working with multi-machine power systems, and I have been struggling with the transformation between the *dq0* and *DQ0* frames. I will first introduce my understanding of these frames, and then ask my question about it.

In power systems, the *dq0* transformation, also called Park's transformation, consists in converting from the static *abc* frame to a rotating *dq0* frame. This transformation slightly differs from author to author depending on the choice of the leading and lagging components.

When considering multi-machine networks, usually all the devices are converted to a same rotating frame with rotation speed equal to the synchronous speed \$\omega_s\$. For this reason, this rotating frame is called synchronously rotating frame, and it is represented by *DQ0* coordinates (capital letters).

However, for transforming from *dq0* to *DQ0* and vice-versa, the transformation matrix also differ from author to author depending on the choice of the leading and lagging components. For instance, when the *q* axis and *D* axis are considered initially aligned, the following transformation matrix is used for converting from *dq0* to *DQ0*, where \$\delta\$ is the angle between the *D* and *q* axes.
$$
\begin{equation*}
    T_{dqos}T_{dqoi}^{-1} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \sin{\delta} & \cos{\delta}\\ -\cos{\delta} & \sin{\delta}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
$$

On the other hand, when the *d* axis is considered initially aligned with the *D* axis, the following transformation matrix is used (here \$\delta^{\star}\$ is the angle between *d* and *D* axes).

$$
\begin{equation}
T_{dqos}^{\star}T_{dqoi}^{\star-1} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos{\delta^{\star}} & -\sin{\delta^{\star}}\\ \sin{\delta^{\star}} & \cos{\delta^{\star}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

Therefore, my question is: how should I define the leading and lagging components? In the case of a multi-machine power system, should the *dq0* frames of all machines be considered either lagging or leading the *DQ0* frame?

I really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: It seems like you have a good understanding of the rotating and synchronous reference frame concept. I'm not clear what you are wanting to know. Are you wondering about the sign convention for delta and delta-star? Or the position conventions for dq vs DQ? Can you clarify your question? If it's about conventions, your choice can be arbitrary as long as you are consistent in it. If you are trying to match some existing software, then refer to that software documentation. E.g. see https://www.powerworld.com/files/Synchronous-Machines.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I am working within a laboratory, and we have our own power system simulator written in MATLAB. I believe the convention being used for the synchronous generators is the first one I mentioned (q and D axes aligned). However I am trying to model voltage source converters, and therefore I got confused about which convention should I follow. In a multi-machine system, every component should follow the same convention for converting from dq to DQ frames?

Comment: It seems to me that in general it would be possible to have different components use different conventions for their model's dq frame as long as the appropriate conversion is used to/from the shared DQ frame. I guess it depends on your power system simulator code as to how that conversion happens and whether it is able to cope with different conversions for different models or not.

Comment: In summary, as long as when I convert the signals back to the DQ frame I use the inverse matrix that I used for converting to the dq frame, the results should be fine? My understanding is the same, but my supervisor is not convinced, and is looking for some evidences on it. Do you know about any site/book/scientific article that addresses this topic?